# Selecting a property from JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a JSON similar to this one:

```
    {"request":
{"Target":"Affiliate_Offer","Format":"json","Service":"HasOffers","Version":"2","NetworkId":"adattract","Method":"getPayoutDetails","api_key":"bd2e82f029c50b582db85868b7c0b8ab99d095886ab079f87b464bb68486c891","offer_id":"9463"},"response":
    {"status":1,"httpStatus":200,"data":{"offer_payout":
    {"payout":"0.820"}},"errors":[],"errorMessage":null}}
```

And I want to select only value of `payout` which is `0.820`.

**Here what I try**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ada  WHERE require_approval='0' ORDER BY i2 ASC LIMIT 0,10") or die(mysql_error());
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<div>";
  $r = $row['id'];
  $ri = $row['i2'];
  // $ri contains no. 1 2 3 4 5..//
  $json = '';
}
$mydata = json_decode($json, true);
$data = $mydata["response"]["data"];
$pay = $data[$ri]["offer_payout"][payout];
echo "</div>";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO thumb(img,id) VALUES('$nth','$oid')");
echo $pay; //output of 0.8200 but not work plz here i need help//
}
?>
```

Comment: It should be `["payout"]` not `[payout]`? Is this the issue you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get values from the json as like that:

```
// your json
$json = '{"request":
{"Target":"Affiliate_Offer","Format":"json","Service":"HasOffers","Version":"2","NetworkId":"adattract","Method":"getPayoutDetails","api_key":"bd2e82f029c50b582db85868b7c0b8ab99d095886ab079f87b464bb68486c891","offer_id":"9463"},"response":
{"status":1,"httpStatus":200,"data":{"offer_payout":
{"payout":"0.82000"}},"errors":[],"errorMessage":null}}';

// json_decode() function with second param true for array format
$json_decoded = json_decode($json,true);

echo $json_decoded['response']['data']['offer_payout']['payout']; //0.82000
```

**How can you get this in your code?**

You just need to change these two lines in your code:

```
$data = $mydata["response"]["data"];
$pay = $data["offer_payout"]['payout']; //0.82000
```

Answer (score 2):

In the vain of *'Give a man a fish and he will feed his family for a day. Teach a man to fish and he will feed his family forever'* here is how you find out what a json object looks like.

```
$json = '{"request":
{"Target":"Affiliate_Offer","Format":"json","Service":"HasOffers","Version":"2","NetworkId":"adattract","Method":"getPayoutDetails","api_key":"bd2e82f029c50b582db85868b7c0b8ab99d095886ab079f87b464bb68486c891","offer_id":"9463"},"response":
{"status":1,"httpStatus":200,"data":{"offer_payout":
{"payout":"0.82000"}},"errors":[],"errorMessage":null}}';


$mydata = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($mydata);
```

Will output this :-

```
Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [Target] => Affiliate_Offer
            [Format] => json
            [Service] => HasOffers
            [Version] => 2
            [NetworkId] => adattract
            [Method] => getPayoutDetails
            [api_key] => bd2e82f029c50b582db85868b7c0b8ab99d095886ab079f87b464bb68486c891
            [offer_id] => 9463
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [httpStatus] => 200
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [offer_payout] => Array
                        (
                            [payout] => 0.82000
                        )

                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [errorMessage] =>
        )

)
```

And now you know how to address any and all fields

So the field you want will be

```
$pay = $mydata["response"]["data"]["offer_payout"]["payout"];
```

Now you decided to convert a `JSON Object` to an `array`, there is no need to do that, and in some ways an object is even easier to address and uses less key strokes than an array.

So leave the `,true` out of the `json_decode` and you get this

```
$json = '{"request":
{"Target":"Affiliate_Offer","Format":"json","Service":"HasOffers","Version":"2","NetworkId":"adattract","Method":"getPayoutDetails","api_key":"bd2e82f029c50b582db85868b7c0b8ab99d095886ab079f87b464bb68486c891","offer_id":"9463"},"response":
{"status":1,"httpStatus":200,"data":{"offer_payout":
{"payout":"0.82000"}},"errors":[],"errorMessage":null}}';


$mydata = json_decode($json);
print_r($mydata);
```

Which outputs :-

```
stdClass Object
(
    [request] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Target] => Affiliate_Offer
            [Format] => json
            [Service] => HasOffers
            [Version] => 2
            [NetworkId] => adattract
            [Method] => getPayoutDetails
            [api_key] => bd2e82f029c50b582db85868b7c0b8ab99d095886ab079f87b464bb68486c891
            [offer_id] => 9463
        )

    [response] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 1
            [httpStatus] => 200
            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [offer_payout] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [payout] => 0.82000
                        )

                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [errorMessage] =>
        )

)
```

Now the field you want to address is :-

```
$pay = $mydata->response->data->offer_payout->payout;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pay = $mydata["response"]["data"]["offer_payout"]["payout"];
```

You might want to cast it to float, as it is a string in the JSON data you provided:

```
$pay = (float) $mydata["response"]["data"]["offer_payout"]["payout"];
```

Comment: **I very much doubt that** converting `0.820` to an integer is going to improve that guys day in any way whatsoever!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `(float)` not `(int)`

Answer (score 0):

First you need convert json to array

```
$array =json_decode($json,TRUE); //$json is converted to array
```

Now you can retrieve any property from the array 
The complete code example is

```
$json = '{"request":
{"Target":"Affiliate_Offer","Format":"json","Service":"HasOffers","Version":"2","NetworkId":"adattract","Method":"getPayoutDetails","api_key":"bd2e82f029c50b582db85868b7c0b8ab99d095886ab079f87b464bb68486c891","offer_id":"9463"},"response":
{"status":1,"httpStatus":200,"data":{"offer_payout":
{"payout":"0.82000"}},"errors":[],"errorMessage":null}}';

$mydata = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($mydata);
```

OutPut:

```
 Array ( [request] => Array ( [Target] => Affiliate_Offer [Format] => json [Service] => HasOffers [Version] => 2 [NetworkId] => adattract [Method] => getPayoutDetails [api_key] => bd2e82f029c50b582db85868b7c0b8ab99d095886ab079f87b464bb68486c891 [offer_id] => 9463 ) [response] => Array ( [status] => 1 [httpStatus] => 200 [data] => Array ( [offer_payout] => Array ( [payout] => 0.82000 ) ) [errors] => Array ( ) [errorMessage] => ) ) 1
```

From the result you can retrieve any array property 
Eg-

```
echo $mydata['response']['status'];
```

OutPut:
1

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
$mydata = json_decode($json, true);
$data = $mydata['response']['data'];
print_r($data);
print_r($data['offer_payout']['payout']);
```